# SSR functionality using ExpressJS with webpack + redux + sass

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, redux, server-side-rendering

I need contribution to add Server-side rendering(SSR) functionality in the existing react application which has pushed to the GitHub repository. The preference is using express.js to add SSR. This application is built on reactJS + redux + webpack + sass

[Click here for the repository](https://github.com/mowais-ac/react-redux-webpack-sass-ssr)

Why pushed in Github and why is it important?
This helps me as well as other developers to kick start the project without any hassle for the development and production platform.

**Looking forward to your contribution.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are already using [react-router](https://github.com/mowais-ac/react-redux-webpack-sass-ssr/blob/main/package.json#L17) so maybe try [this](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/server-rendering).Not sure what your question is though if the question is why use SSR then usually you use it to get quicker first meaningful paint (if you pre hydrate the data that comes from async), you can cache shared async on the server (useful for expensive 3rd party api that don't change often) and good for search engine optimization.

Comment: the purpose of the repository and question is, I am struggling to make my application SSR, so I won't be able to get any help anywhere, so I pushed my code to github where I  want from experts to achieve the same, BTW I used all very common and very useful plugins into this, if some one can do it, It will be really helpful for react-starter